# Custom Protocol conformances for ViewModel in swift in MVVM for Input and Output types

Tags: swift, input, mvvm, uikit, viewmodel

I want to create base protocol for Input, Output, and ViewModel for my MVVM architecture. Here is my current implementation for that purpose.

I really want to write code-like-that.

But the problem is that XCode complains that `No type for 'Self.Input' can satisfy both 'Self.Input == any MyViewModelInput' and 'Self.Input : ViewModelInput'` when I try to declare `MyViewModel` protocol.

Here are my topics that I want to be satisfied:

- `ViewModelInput` is generic protocol that allows me to use default implementation for some functions
- `ViewModelOutput` is generic protocol that allows me to use default implementation for some functions
- ViewModel's Input and Output are typed by `ViewModelInput` and `ViewModelOutput`
- There is `MyViewModel` protocol that conforms to the `ViewModel` protocol with appropriate `Input` and `Output` associatedtype-s

---

```
protocol ViewModelInput {
    func onViewDidLoad()
}

extension ViewModelInput {
    func onViewDidLoad() {}
}

protocol ViewModelOutput { }

protocol ViewModel: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Input: ViewModelInput
    associatedtype Output: ViewModelOutput
}

protocol MyViewModelInput: ViewModelInput { }
protocol MyViewModelOutput: ViewModelOutput { }

// [On this bottom line there is error: `No type for 'Self.Input' can satisfy both 'Self.Input == any MyViewModelInput'
protocol MyViewModel: ViewModel           
    where Input == MyViewModelInput, 
          Output == MyViewModelOutput { }

final class DefaultMyViewModel: MyViewModel { }
```

How can I change the code so that is satisfies my criteria and there is no remaining error?

Comment: So you have 7 different protocols for this!!! (And you didn't include the definition of `ViewModel`)

Comment: Hi, Joakim. Yes, I have 7 different protocols and the definition of the ViewModel is included in the code.

Comment: Ah, yes now I see it. Not sure why I missed it before. Anyway, I can't see the reason why you need so many protocols because it all becomes very abstract. The error seems pretty clear to me, `Input` is required to conform to `ViewModelInput` but `MyViewModelInput` doesn't extend that protocol

Comment: I am really sorry, I have missed the conformance. It is actually mentioned in the actual code. Please have a look one more time since the code in the description in updated, but as I have mentioned, still having that error.

Comment: Changing `==` to `:` in the `where` condition will silence the compiler error

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Joakim Danielson,

> Changing `==` to `:` in the where condition will silence the compiler error

And it worked adequately.